# Numberformat that allows me to enter formulas but stores values as text?

Tags: vba, excel, number-formatting

Is it possible to set the numberformat in a cell/column using either Excel or VBA so that:

- if I enter a formula (anything starting with =) Excel will calculate the formula (and not interpret it as just text)
- if I enter a value, for example 5.80, Excel will store it as text?

I'm having a problem where I want all user input to be stored as text, but users should also be able to enter formulas. If I set the numberformat to text, formulas aren't interpreted. If I set the numberformat to general, values are stored as numbers.

Comment: It is possible that, if you state why you want all as text, people give you better options. Just a suggestion...

Comment: Good input! Two reasons: *I don't want decimals to be automatically deleted, *Values will be matched with text in other sheets and thus to be matched without any problem they should be text

Comment: When you do the matching in the second sheet, is there any reason why you can't cast the values in sheet 1 to string during comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my version.

Format all cells in that sheet as `Text`. This code uses `Application.Evaluate()` to evaluate all formulas and store the result as text.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim aCell As Range

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    '~~> You need this in case user copies formula
    '~~> from another sheet
    Target.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"

    '~~> Looping though all the cells in case user
    '~~> copies formula from another sheet
    For Each aCell In Target.Cells
        If Left(aCell.Formula, 1) = "=" Then _
        aCell.Value = Application.Evaluate(aCell.Formula)
    Next

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Comment: A very clever approach!

Comment: I don't understand, why do I need Target.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"? Will it cause decimals to be removed? I don't want decimals to be removed

Comment: Not it will not remove the decimals. The reason why you need that line is becuase if you copy a formula from another sheet and paste it in this sheet then even the formats will get copied. If you want two decima places then use this `aCell.Value = Format(Application.Evaluate(aCell.Formula),"0.00")`

Comment: `Target.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"` ensures that the formatting of the cells is changed back to "Text" if in case the formatting changes when you copy paste.

Answer (score 3):

Easy...........pre-format the cell to *Text*, then have an *Event* macro monitor the cell and change the format to *General* if a formula is entered; and then force formula execution.  For example cell **B9**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim B9 As Range
    Set B9 = Range("B9")
    If Intersect(Target, B9) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With B9
        If Left(.Value, 1) = "=" Then
            .NumberFormat = "General"
            .Value = .Value
        Else
            .NumberFormat = "@"
        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: ++ Even I would go in for `Worksheet_Change`. Though a slightly different version :)

Comment: How would I write this event handler if I want the range to be an entire column?

Comment: I see that Siddharta Rout had a similar answer where he loops all cells in a range, so I got an answer to my question above from his answer. Thank you for a very clever approach!

Answer (score 1):

Conditional Formatting

Highlight range you want affected and click conditional formatting.  Apply as shown below.  You want to format cells not containing text "=" to "text".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can force Excel to interpret a number as a string by appending a single quote to the start of the number even if the cell format is set to General:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "'5.80"
'...or...
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).Value = "'" & Format$(58 / 10, "#.00")
```